# Why is React.memo not working with useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm kind of new to react, so what i wanted was that, I have a toggle button to toggle a persons component and I have a cockpit component. But whenever I toggle the persons component, I don't want to always re-render the cockpit component.

So this is my Cockpit.js component file.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

import classes from './Cockpit.css';

const cockpit = props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('[Cockpit.js] useEffect');
    // Http request...
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert('Saved data to cloud!');
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      console.log('[Cockpit.js] cleanup work in useEffect');
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('[Cockpit.js] 2nd useEffect');
    return () => {
      console.log('[Cockpit.js] cleanup work in 2nd useEffect');
    };
  });

  // useEffect();

  const assignedClasses = [];
  let btnClass = '';
  if (props.showPersons) {
    btnClass = classes.Red;
  }

  if (props.personsLength <= 2) {
    assignedClasses.push(classes.red); // classes = ['red']
  }
  if (props.personsLength <= 1) {
    assignedClasses.push(classes.bold); // classes = ['red', 'bold']
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.Cockpit}>
      <h1>{props.title}</h1>
      <p className={assignedClasses.join(' ')}>This is really working!</p>
      <button className={btnClass} onClick={props.clicked}>
        Toggle Persons
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default React.memo(cockpit);
```

And this is my App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Persons from '../Components/Persons/Persons';
import classes from './App.css';
import Cockpit from '../Components/Cockpit/Cockpit'

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("[App.js] constructor");
  }

  state = {
    persons: [{id: "abc", name: "", age: 45}, 
    {id: "azz", name: "", age: 56},
    {id: "asq", name: "", age: 62}],
    showPersons: false,
    showCockpit: true
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    console.log("[App.js] getDerivedStateFromProps", props)
    return state; 
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('[App.js] componentDidMount')
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    console.log('[App.js] shouldCompoentUpdate');
    return true;
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('[App.js] componentDidUpdate')
  }

  deletePersonHandler = (i) => {
    const persons = [...this.state.persons];
    persons.splice(i, 1);
    this.setState({persons: persons})
  }
  switchNameHandler = (newName) => {
    this.setState({persons: [{name: newName, age: 50}, {name: "Aysha", age: 56}, {name: "Momma", age: 62}]})
  }

  nameSwitchHandler = (event, id) => {
    const personIndex = this.state.persons.findIndex(p => {
      return p.id === id;
    })

    const person = {...this.state.persons[personIndex]}

    person.name = event.target.value;

    const persons = [...this.state.persons]
    persons[personIndex] = person;
    this.setState({persons: persons})
  }

  togglePersonHandler = () => {
    let doesChange = this.state.showPersons;
    this.setState({showPersons: !doesChange})
  }

  render() {

    console.log("[App.js] render");
    let person = null;

    if(this.state.showPersons) {
      person = (<Persons 
        persons={this.state.persons}
        clicked={this.deletePersonHandler}
        changed={this.nameSwitchHandler} />
      );
    }

    return (
      <div className={classes.App}> 
      <button onClick={() => this.setState({showCockpit: false})}>Remove Cockpit</button>
        {this.state.showCockpit ? (<Cockpit 
        title={this.props.appTitle}
        showPersons={this.state.showPersons}
        personsLength={this.state.persons.length}
        clicked={this.togglePersonHandler} />) : null}
        {person}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

But even when I toggle it, useEffect in cockpit component still console logs in the browser console when its not supposed to. I can't seem to find what I am doing wrong.

As you can see in this image the useEffect component in cockpit still renders in the console......
[Browser Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WC8rb.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`React.memo` will do a shallow equal comparison on the `props` object by default. That means it will check every top level item in the props for equality and if any of them changed it will re-render.

When you click your persons toggle button it will change `showPersons` in your `App` component wich is also a prop that you pass to `<Cockpit>`. Therefore it will re-render even with `React.memo`. If it wouldn't re-render it wouldn't correctly update your Button class adding or removing `classes.Red` because this is dependent on the `showPersons` prop.

It has nothing to do with your `useEffect` inside of `cockpit` which will only get called after it re-renders but doesn't cause it to re-render in the first place.

Comment: Thanks alot, that makes more sense now. I was lacking an understanding of how really React.memo works, this helped me understand what my real mistake was.

Answer (score 1):

On the click of Toggle Persons, you are changing the state in App Component.
This results in the re-rendering of the App and Cockpit components.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log('[Cockpit.js] 2nd useEffect');
    return () => {
      console.log('[Cockpit.js] cleanup work in 2nd useEffect');
    };
  });
```

The above code will trigger every render as you haven't provided dependency.
To fix this, you need to add a dependency to the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Since `showPersons` change it detects it as changed props.

You can add an equality function in `React.memo` that tells react when to consider the memoization stale:

```js
// Will only rerender when someValue changes
export default React.memo(Cockpit, (oldProps, newProps) => oldProps.someValue === newProps.someValue)
```